# cmd script, How to pass token variable(say %%a) to a call

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, cmd

This is my first question so please bare.

serverlist= abc,def,xyz,....
for each of these items i get another comma seperated list b=apple,ball,cat...

I have a batch script that has a nested loop which does the following

```
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 for %%a in ("%serverlist:,=" "%") do (
 for /F "delims= " %%b in ( XXXXXXX) do (  
 echo a is %%~a
 echo b is %%~b
 call :header %%a %%b
 echo --------
 )
 )

 :header
 (
 echo inside header values are  %1 %2 
 )
```

OUTPUT:

```
---------------------------------------------
 a is abc
 b is apple,ball,cat
 inside header values are "abc" apple
 --------
 a is def
 b is apple,ball,cat
 inside header values are "def " apple
 --------
```

I need to get the complete list of `b` in the `:header` to process it further. 
As of now I am only getting the first element of b in call.

Comment: Quote the arguments: `call :header "%%a" "%%b"`?

Comment: Awesome! that worked. Thanks

Comment: Use `call :header "%%~a" "%%~b"` in the main loop and `%~1` and `%~2` in the sub-routine to unquote the items...

Comment: To avoid subroutines being run finally again they should be delimited by a goto :eof from program flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting together a formal answer from the comments:

1. If arguments to a batch subroutine have spaces or commas, you should quote your arguments when you call the subroutine: `call :header "%%a" "%%b"`.
2. (thanks to [aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl)) Within the subroutine, to unquote the arguments for processing, use `%~1` and `%~2`. You can find out more about variable manipulation at [SS64's SYNTAX section](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html), specifically the pages on [variables](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html), [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html), and [substrings](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html).
3. (thanks to [LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings)) Protect your subroutines; immediately before the entry point, put an unconditional `GOTO` to prevent execution from "falling into" the routine.